# is there any way to get the following data frame in python pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
ID  Distance
100007  0
100007  0
100007  0
100007  0
100007  0
100007  0
100013  39.22
100013  39.21
100013  39.21
100013  39.20
100013  39.19
100013  39.19
100013  39.21
100019  20.28
100019  29.74
100019  29.70
100019  29.73
```

From the above data Frame I want to get this:

```
ID      d1        d2    d3        d4      d5     d6      d7
100007  0          0    0          0       0      0 
100013  39.22   39.21   39.21   39.20   39.19   39.19   39.21
100019  20.2    29.74   29.70   29.73
```

How can I get this by using python 3 pandas? Please help me with this, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

```
res = (df
       .astype(str)
       .groupby("ID")
       .Distance.agg(",".join)
       .str.split(",",expand=True)
      )


res.columns = [ent+1 for ent in res.columns]
res.add_prefix("d")

         d1     d2      d3      d4      d5      d6      d7
ID                          
100007  0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     None
100013  39.22   39.21   39.21   39.2    39.19   39.19   39.21
100019  20.28   29.74   29.7    29.73   None    None    None
```

Answer (score 1):

```
g = df.groupby('ID')['Distance'].agg(list).to_list()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(g, columns=['d{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, len(max(g, key=len))+1)])
print(pd.concat([pd.Series(df['ID'].unique()), df2], axis=1).rename(columns={0:'ID'}))
```

Prints:

```
       ID     d1     d2     d3     d4     d5     d6     d7
0  100007   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00    NaN
1  100013  39.22  39.21  39.21  39.20  39.19  39.19  39.21
2  100019  20.28  29.74  29.70  29.73    NaN    NaN    NaN
```